# ASP.NET two-way bind a nested listview with a variable amount of items

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding, webforms, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to figure out how to two-way databind a ListView. Coming from MVC to a Web Forms application, I'm struggling on how to do so.

I've created a view model structure that represents the nested hiearchy in the SharePoint application. I'm looking to have the two-way binding work against my view model, which I can then transpose into my SharePoint data source:

> ```
> Line of Business
>   Solution Line
>     Product Code (user can "check" if the product code should be applied)
> ```

*View Model Hierarchy:*

```
 public class AddCustomerViewModel
    {
        public IList<LineOfBusinessViewModel> LinesOfBusiness { get; set; }

        public AddCustomerViewModel()
        {
            LinesOfBusiness = new List<LineOfBusinessViewModel>();
        }
    }

public class LineOfBusinessViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<SolutionLineViewModel> SolutionLines { get; set; }

    public LineOfBusinessViewModel()
    {
        SolutionLines = new List<SolutionLineViewModel>();
    }
}

public class SolutionLineViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductCodeViewModel> ProductCodes { get; set; }

    public SolutionLineViewModel()
    {
        ProductCodes = new List<ProductCodeViewModel>();
    }
}

public class ProductCodeViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

*ASPX Page:*

```
<asp:ListView ID="LineOfBusinessListView" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ItemType="ViewModel.AddCustomer.LineOfBusinessViewModel" ItemPlaceholderID="lobPlaceHolderId">
<LayoutTemplate>                    
    <ul>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="lobPlaceHolderId"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ul>                    
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <li>
        <%# Item.Title %>
        <asp:ListView ID="SolutionLinesView" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" DataSource="<%# Item.SolutionLines %>" ItemType="ViewModel.AddCustomer.SolutionLineViewModel" ItemPlaceholderID="solutionLinePlaceHolderId">
            <LayoutTemplate>                                
                <ul>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="solutionLinePlaceHolderId"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ul>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <%# Item.Title %>
                    <asp:ListView ID="ProductCodeView" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" DataSource="<%# Item.ProductCodes %>" ItemType="ViewModel.AddCustomer.ProductCodeViewModel" ItemPlaceholderID="productCodePlaceHolderId" OnDataBinding="ProductCodeView_DataBinding">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <ul>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="productCodePlaceHolderId"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            </ul>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                <%# Item.Title %>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="productCode" Checked="<%# BindItem.IsChecked %>" runat="server" />
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

*Code Behind:*

```
protected AddCustomerViewModel AddCustomerViewModel { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        AddCustomerViewModel = new AddCustomerViewModel();

        // Construct view model heiarchy...

        LineOfBusinessListView.DataSource = AddCustomerViewModel.LinesOfBusiness;
        LineOfBusinessListView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

How can I properly two-way bind the view model to the nested ListViews (one-way binding is working), and how can I retrieve these bound values on post-back/form-submission?

**Edit:**
One awkward thing I noticed, was that in order to use `BindItem` for the checkbox element, I needed to define an ID. However, the items are dynamic, so defining a "static" ID won't do, and I'm unsure how to dynamically set a ID.

*ASP.NET Web Forms 4.5, c#*

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @the_lotus unfortunately no. To get around this, I manually parsed the Request.form.Allkeys postback to get the name/value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a straight forward answer to this. It is possible to parse the `Request.form.Allkeys` to get the posted name/value pairs, but this gets incredibly hairy, pretty quick.

For our solution, since this was a "green" project, we ended up switching up our server-side network calls to .NET Web API 2, which really simplified binding.